# Как в Unix с помощью Shell вычилить суммарный объем памяти, занимаемый файлами в подкатологе и средний объем файла?

Tags: unix, shell

Как в Unix с помощью Shell вычилить суммарный объем памяти, занимаемый файлами вподкатологе и средний объем файла? ?

Comment: `man du` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

num="$(find $1 -type f | wc -l)"
sz="$(du -k -s $1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
avg="$((sz / num))"

echo "number of files: $num"
echo "size: $sz KiB"
echo "average file: $avg KiB"
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `ls` / `grep` / `awk`:

```
ls -lk subdir/|grep "^[-]"|awk '{sum+=$5;num=FNR}END{print"Files: "num;print"Size: "sum;print"Average Size: "int(sum/num)}'
```